# "cannot find symbol variable BufferUtils"

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to load an image into Java to create a texture in JoGL. I need to use a call to BufferUtils for this:

```
dest = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length * BufferUtils.SIZEOF_INT);
```

But it's telling me that it can't find it. This is all I have imported:

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.*;
import com.sun.opengl.util.*;
import com.sun.opengl.util.j2d.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean [BufferUtil](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/nightly/javadoc_public/com/sun/opengl/util/BufferUtil.html) (no 's').